# How do I integrate ActiveMQ with a HornetQ ESB (or access the HornetQ directly from C#)?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, activemq-classic, hornetq

I've got an ActiveMQ ESB that I am using between several C# assemblies across a couple different systems. I need to start receiving notifications being sent out by a new system from it's HornetQ ESB. As far as I can tell the HornetQ is pre-2.0.0GA.

I'd like to just use Camel to set up routing between the HornetQ ESB and my ActiveMQ ESB, but so far we haven't been able to get even that far. I'm not sure how much flexibility I've got to change the HornetQ configuration (say to add support for StompConnect or something like that).

Does anyone of a viable option for getting access to the HornetQ ESB through ActiveMQ (or directly from C# if necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect camel to HornetQ using the [Camel JMS Component](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) - and route that to the [Camel ActiveMQ Component directly](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html). You can use Camel inside the ActiveMQ broker to do this - see [Enterprise Integration Patterns in ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes use STOMP :)

http://stomp.codehaus.org/

http://jmesnil.net/weblog/2010/01/14/using-stomp-with-hornetq/

Answer (score -1):

The Camel plugin ended up working. We had tried this originally, but had some other configuration issues that prevented it from working (we hadn't configured HornetQ to allow remote consumers). Thanks for the help.